# Is it possible to embed fonts at runtime to use for existing dynamic textfield instances in SWFs?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, embed, textfield

I'm trying to embed fonts at runtime in actionscript and it somewhat works. I can embed fonts by either using the embed tag or by loading a font library asset with a linkage name and use it with a new TextField. However, a textfield that exists on a movie clip already does not have the embedded font and is missing characters.

A quick example in code (textInstance exists on the movieclip):

```
var embeddedFonts = Font.enumerateFonts(); //Shows embedded font

var textFormat:TextFormat = textInstance.getTextFormat();

textInstance.text = "Don't be lazy"; //missing characters 

var textField:TextField = new TextField();

textField.embedFonts = true;
textField.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
textField.selectable = false;
textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
textField.multiline = true;

textField.text = "Don't be lazy"; //shows all characters
addChild(textField);
```

Is it possible to do this? I want to embed the font at runtime and I'm loading multiple SWFs and I don't want to embed the font in each SWF.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have `textInstance` already added to your swf and it has a `TextFormat` with the font you are loading later.

After loading your font into your swf you should either set the text again with `textInstance.text = textInstance.text` (if `textInstance` has a `defaultTextFormat`) or set the textFormat with `textInstance.setTextFormat(textFormat)`, because the textfield doesn't update automatically upon loading a font.

Comment: No dice. The text is still missing characters :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a new TextFormat with the font and set it as the defaultTextFormat in order to get it to work.